# Pointer arithmic for arrays which are members of a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I realized the following problem:

```
struct S{
   double **A;
 }
 struct S s;
 s.A = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double*)*2);
 s.A[0] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
 s.A[1] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
```

Now let us say I want to do pointer arithmetic of `s.A`. 
If I start by defining a pointer to a double like:

```
double ptr
ptr = &s.A[0][0];
```

I  will expect that

`*(ptr+1)` is equivalent to `s.A[0][1]`

`*(ptr+2)` is equivalent to `s.A[0][2]`

`*(ptr+3)` is equivalent to `s.A[1][0]`

I realize that   `*(ptr+3)` is NOT equivalent to `s.A[1][0]` and points to a wrong address. To point to `s.A[1][0]` I need to do `*(ptr+4)`, so jumping with 1. Can anyone explain why I need to jump an extra one when I want to begin at the next row, and how will I do it if I had to start at the third, fourth etc rows?

Comment: Use `s.A = malloc(sizeof(*(s.A))*2)` instead

Comment: would that help?

Comment: Not with your actual problem, but it is so much better. https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/6699433

Comment: What you create is a so-called [*jagged* array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array). For a "true" 2D array, (like `double a[2][3];`) you have to remember that it's actually an array of arrays, and what you have is a 1D array of pointers. You can solve it by creating an array of `2 * 3` elements, and through some extra arithmetic treat it as a 2D array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks very much for the thread and the advice. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Is it because it is a member of a struct. Although, in my real application I would need to keep my 2D array as part of the struct. So how it that be possible

Comment: As for `ptr = &s.A[0][0]`, that makes `ptr` be a pointer to the first element of `s.A[0]` only. Because `s.A` is an array of pointers, there's really no relation to `s.A[1]` at all.

Comment: No it doesn't matter that it's a structure member, that is totally irrelevant. The problem is the nature of your "arrays": You have an array of two unrelated pointers.

Comment: Really? So if you needed to have an array such as `s.A` being contigous to do better chache utilisation and vectorisation etc, this is all not really possible?

Comment: Now I get what you mean, so how would I I dynamically allocate such a truly 2D array?
I though you could only do this with double pointers in C

Comment: Like I said previously, allocate a single array of `M * N` elements, where `M` is the number of "rows" and `N` is the number of columns. In your case it would be `2 * 3`. So `malloc(sizeof(double) * 2 * 3)` to create a single contiguous array of elements.

Comment: On another note, please don't use explicit pointer arithmetic. For any pointer *or array* `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter (`p[i]`) is usually easier to read and understand, and less to write as well.

Comment: Ahh, okay. And the compiler would be able to cope with for example accesssing the array like a 2D array, such as `s.A[0][2] `

Comment: Not if you have a single array allocation. Then you need to do some extra arithmetic to get the correct index. You could easily find out yourself with the help of a pen and some paper, or find one of the several thousands examples that exists all over the Internet.

Comment: I get the feeling that you're trying to write "clever" code that will come and bite you in the future. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you allocate the pointers at:

```
s.A[0] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
s.A[1] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*3);
```

you get what addresses the operating system gives you. Not like an array, it doesn't have to be consecutive.